# ATBSWP Chapter 4 practice project: Comma Code

Tags: python, list

So the practice project is as follows:

Say you have a list value like this: `spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']`
Write a function that takes a list value as an argument and returns a string with all the items separated by a comma and a space, with and inserted before the last item. For example, passing the previous `spam` list to the function would return `'apples, bananas, tofu, and cats'`. But your function should be able to work with any list value passed to it.

So far I've come up with this:

```
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']

def commacode(a_list):
    a_list.insert(-1, 'and')
    print(a_list)

commacode(spam)
```

And of course the output is just the list values.  I've tried to make line 5 as `print(str(a_list))`, but that gives a syntax error. My line of thinking is that I have to change it to a string, but I'm lost. Am I missing something in the chapter? I've felt like I've gone over it several times. I feel like `len(a_list)` should be somewhere in there but that would just give me a value of `5`.  Any thoughts, or how I should go about thinking about this would be great help. I always feel like I'm really understanding this stuff and then I get to these practice projects and am ALWAYS confused on what to do.  I know the practice projects are going to use some information we've learned in previous chapters and then focus mainly on the chapter we are on. Chapter 4 covers lists, list values, string values, tuples, `copy.copy()`, and `copy.deepcopy()` just to name a few.

Link - [Chapter4](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter4/)

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved the problem:

```
def commaCode(eggs):
    return ', '.join(map(str,eggs[:-1])) + ' and ' + str(eggs[-1])
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
print(commaCode(spam))
```

Output:

> apples, bananas, tofu and cats

join() and map() wasn't discussed in the chapter. I learnt them while googling how to convert list into string.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on the solution. It utilizes everything we have learned through this chapter.

```
def pr_list(listothings):

    for i in range(len(listothings)-1):
        print(listothings[i] + ', ', end='')

spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']

pr_list(spam)

print('and ' + spam[-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

I've started with Python and with the book from Al Sweigart. At this point in chapter 4, I also struggled with my ideas to solve the practice. So I found here your entries and like to show the community my solution (to be onest after a while and several tries):

```py
def adapList(xList, xAdd):
    xList[-1] = xAdd + xList[-1]
    print(xList)
```

The input:
`adapList(spam, 'and ')`

The result:

```
['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'and cats']
```

Pleasd feel free to comment my solution, I'm happy to learn from your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following `commacode` function:

```
monty = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats', 'dogs', 'pigs']

def commacode(listname):  
    listname[len(listname) - 1] = 'and ' + listname[len(listname) - 1]  
    index = 0  
    new_string = listname[index]  
    while index < len(listname) - 1:
        new_string = new_string +  ', ' + listname[index + 1]  
        index = index + 1  
        if index == len(listname) - 1: 
            print(new_string)

commacode(monty)
```

Answer (score 0):

new to Python myself, now this is NOT the best possible option I agree, but this is what I came up with.

```
def sentence(conc):

    print(str(conc[:-1]).strip('[]') + ' and ' + str(conc[-1]) + '. ')

spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
ham = ['cats', 'dogs', 'badgers', 'mushrooms']
eggs = [1, 2, 3, 4]

sentence(spam)
sentence(ham)
sentence(eggs)
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem using just the contents of the chapter would result in a very long and tedious program. Instead you could just use the join() function [not given in the chapter] and with a few tweaks you don't even need to use map.

This is how my program looked:

```
def comma(a):
    list_string=','.join(a[0:-1])+' and '+str(a[-1])
    print(list_string)

spam=[]
while True:
    print('Enter the list item of index '+str(len(spam))+' (or enter nothing to stop)')
    item=input()
    if item=='':
        break
    spam= spam+[item]
print('The items are arranged as:')
comma(spam)
```

And yes, in this program, the user has to input the values (similar to a solved question in the chapter)

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share my solution for this one, would love to hear your thoughts:

```
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
counter = 0

for i in spam:
  if counter < len(spam)-2:
    print(spam[counter] + ", ", end='')
    counter += 1

  elif counter == len(spam)-2:
    print(spam[-2] + " and " + spam[-1]) 
    counter += 1
```

Result is: apples, bananas, tofu and cats

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to share my solution with you. It uses join().

```
def function(x):
    print(', '.join(x[:-1]) + ' and ' + x[-1])

spam=['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu','cats']
function(spam)
```

It works like a charm for the purpose of the excercise in chapter 4.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation of the problem.

```
def commaCode(in_list):

    if (len(in_list) == 1):
        print(in_list[0])
    elif (len(in_list) == 0):
        print('Your list is empty.')
    else:
        for i in range(len(in_list) -1):
            print(in_list[i] + ', ', end='')

    if (len(in_list) > 1):
        print('and ' + in_list[-1] + '.')


input_list = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
commaCode(input_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me the only issue I see with it is the when you input apples there is a space at the beginning of the text.

```
spam = ['apples','bananas','tofu','cats']

print('Write tthe name of one of the items on the following list: '
  'apples, bananas, tofu, or cats')

listItem = input()
listItem = int(spam.index(listItem))

def function():
    print(*spam[:listItem], sep = ", " , end = " ")
    print(*spam[listItem+1:], sep = ", " , end = " ")
    print('and ' + spam[listItem])
function()
```

Comment: Hi David, this doesn't appear to do quite what the OP asked. There is an extra space and a missing comma, and requires user input to actually run the program.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new with python but I have some knowledge of javascript, I designed this code for the "Comma Code" practice project of the book Automate the boring stuff with python.

First, I create an empty list. I ask the user to enter a value which will be stored in the empty list I created. It all happens in a `while` loop, for which if the user keeps entering values, the program will keep adding them to the list, but if the user, instead of entering a value, just clicks enter, the program will call the function `commaSpace()` and then break the loop.

For the `commaSpace()` function, I created a variable named `listaFinal` with an empty string for it to be the space where the indexes of the list will be stored and later printed.

In a `for` loop I made two conditions. The first condition says that if `x+1<len(lista)` (which means that any index but the last will do the condition) then the value of the index will be stored in a variable called `valorLista` and then adds the `', '`. That value will be stored in the variable `listaFinal`.
For the second condition, `if x+1==len(lista)` (which is the last item of the list), then the item will be stored in the variable `valorLista` with an `'and '` before the item, and after that, it will be added to the variable `listaFinal`. After all this, the program will print the result.

```
def commaSpace(lista):
listaFinal = ''
for x in range(len(lista)):
    if x + 1 < len(lista):
        valorLista = lista[x] + ', '
        listaFinal = listaFinal + valorLista
    elif x + 1 == len(lista):
        valorLista = 'and ' + lista[x]
        listaFinal = listaFinal + valorLista
print(listaFinal)

lista = []
i = 0
while True:
    print('Enter the value number ' + str(i) + ':' )
    name = input()
    if name == '':
        commaSpace(lista)
        break
    lista = lista + [name]
    i += 1
```

Comment: Welcome. Thanks for contributing. This answer would be improved if you left out unnecessary, irrelevant chatter, such as the 1st paragraph. Next, thanks for explanation. SO frowns on code only Answers, & quite often we need to inform users why it's necessary to highlight & explain how/why important parts of their solution addresses & solves the OP's issue. However, in this case, perhaps you went a little too far? I guess the right balance is subjective. It would be easier to read so much text if you broke it up a little. 2 spaces at EOL+LF will create a paragraph. Wrap inline code in backtics.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Python and programming as a whole and relying heavily on "automate the boring stuff" to learn. Based on the content covered in the book to this chapter containing the project, here is what I could come up with

```
def comma_code(list):
    new_list = []
    for i in range(len(list)-1):
        new_list.append(list[i] + ",")
    new_list.append("and " + list[-1])
 
    for i in new_list:
        print(i, end=" ")

comma_code(spam)
```

Answer (score 0):

Good going friends! Here is my little contribution.

```
list1 = []

def addGrocery(param1):
    print('Your list has ', end="")
    for i in range(len(param1)):
        if i < (len(param1) - 2):
            print(param1[i - 1] + ', ', end="")        
        elif i < (len(param1) - 1):
            print(param1[i - 1] + ' ', end="")
        else:
            print('and ' + param1[i - 1],end="")        

addMore = 'y'

while addMore == 'y':
    print('Enter the grocery item that you want to order')
    inp = input()
    list1.append(inp)
    print(list1[-1] + ' added')
    print('Do you want to add more groceries? - y/n')
    addMore = input().lower()

if addMore == 'n':
    addGrocery(list1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way I did it using only what is taught up until Chapter 4. The instruction in the book mentioned how the code should still work with an empty list. Hence the try and except block. In the book, the author also said the function should return a string which is why I don't put print() in the function.

```
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']

def comma_code(a_list):
    compilation = '' #initiate an empty string to collect the values in the list
    try:
        while True:
            for i in a_list[:-1]: #only loop until the last item
                compilation += str(i) + ', '
            break
        return compilation + ' and ' + str(a_list[-1])
    except:
        return "It's empty yo. Give me a list to work with"
    
comma_code(spam)
```

Took me an hour to figure out how to do it strictly using what's available up to chapter 4.

Answer (score 0):

```
def converster(item):
    stItem = ''
    new = ''
    for i in range(len(item)-1):
        stItem = str(item[i]) + ', '
        new = new + stItem
    new = new + 'and ' + str(item[-1]) 
    return new 
           
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
converster(spam)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take. Please let me know your comments

```
def listToString (oneList):
    s = ''
    for i in range (len(spam)-1):
       s =  s+', ' + spam[i]
    s = s + ' and ' + spam[-1]
    s = s[2::]
    return s

spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
print(listToString(spam))
```

Answer (score 0):

I just started learning python a few months ago, so if there are any problems please let me know. I came up with this after a little help from the internet. I also had a little help from the answers in this post.

```
`spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
 spam2 = ['hello', 'lets', 'go', 'ROCK']
 spam3 = []
def convert(new):
    string = ' '
    for i in new:
        if i == new[-2]:
            string += str(i) + ', and '
        elif i == new[-1]:
            string += str(i) + ''
        else:
            string += str(i) + ', '
    print(string)
 convert(spam)
 convert(spam2)
 convert(spam3)`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def pet(someRandom):
  for some in someRandom[0:len(someRandom)-1]:
       print(some,",",end=" ")
  for some in someRandom[-1:len(someRandom)]:
         print("and",some,".",end=" ")
```

spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
pet(spam)