# Chapter 4 Comma Code - extension

Tags: python-3.x

Original question from the book Automate the Boring at the end of Chapter 4,

**Comma Code [written in Python 3.x]**

> Say you have a list value like this:
>
> ```
> spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
> ```
>
> Write a function that takes a list value as an argument and returns a
>   string with all the items separated by a comma and a space, with `'and'`
>   inserted before the last item. For example, passing the previous
>   `spam` list to the function would return `'apples, bananas, tofu, and
>   cats'`. But your function should be able to work with any list value
>   passed to it.

My question is:
I wish to modify the resulting code which is written in Python 3.x to take in a list at the command prompt such as: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` and have the program put out `1, 2, 3, 4 and 5` I have accomplished this part as you will see from my (very long) code. The problem comes when I have a list of numbers and names or words in it and want this result, I type in at the command prompt: `1, 2, 3, 4, jeremy, anna` and want the following output: `1, 2, 3, 4, jeremy and anna`
As you will see from my code I have left out the rest of the alphabet to keep it brief just for the purpose of finding the solution. How I have tried to solve this problem is using the regular expression functions such as search etc and search for the commas in the output and the logic was to get positions of those commas and then replace the last comma with an `'and'` string. But I could not find anything to achieve that.

p.s. My code (below) has used the answer given by someone on Stack Overflow to the original Comma Code problem, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36191668/atbswp-chapter-4-practice-project-comma-code)

```
#! python3.
#import re
my_input = list(input('Please enter a list of words and or numbers separated by commas:\n'))

def commacode(listname):  

 #if the last entry is equal to a number between 0 and 9 put an "and" before it then print the modified input to screen       
    if listname[len(listname) - 1] == '0':

        listname[len(listname) - 1] = 'and ' + listname[len(listname) -1]
        index = 0  
        new_string = listname[index]  
        while index < len(listname)-1:
            new_string = new_string + listname[index + 1]

            index = index + 1
            if index == len(listname)-1:
                print('\n') 
                print(new_string)

    elif listname[len(listname) - 1] == '1':
        listname[len(listname) - 1] = 'and ' + listname[len(listname) -1]
        index = 0  
        new_string = listname[index]  
        while index < len(listname)-1:
            new_string = new_string + listname[index + 1]

            index = index + 1
            if index == len(listname)-1:
                print('\n') 
                print(new_string)

    elif listname[len(listname) - 1] == '2':
        listname[len(listname) - 1] = 'and ' + listname[len(listname) -1]
        index = 0  
        new_string = listname[index]  
        while index < len(listname)-1:
            new_string = new_string + listname[index + 1]

            index = index + 1
            if index == len(listname)-1:
                print('\n') 
                print(new_string)

    elif listname[len(listname) - 1] == '3':
        listname[len(listname) - 1] = 'and ' + listname[len(listname) -1]
        index = 0  
        new_string = listname[index]  
        while index < len(listname)-1:
            new_string = new_string + listname[index + 1]

            index = index + 1
            if index == len(listname)-1:
                print('\n') 
                print(new_string)            

    elif listname[len(listname) - 1] == '4':
        listname[len(listname) - 1] = 'and ' + listname[len(listname) -1]
        index = 0  
        new_string = listname[index]  
        while index < len(listname)-1:
            new_string = new_string + listname[index + 1]

            index = index + 1
            if index == len(listname)-1:
                print('\n') 
                print(new_string)         

    elif listname[len(listname) - 1] == '5':
        listname[len(listname) - 1] = 'and ' + listname[len(listname) -1]
        index = 0  
        new_string = listname[index]  
        while index < len(listname)-1:
            new_string = new_string + listname[index + 1]

            index = index + 1
            if index == len(listname)-1:
                print('\n') 
                print(new_string)

    elif listname[len(listname) - 1] == '6':
        listname[len(listname) - 1] = 'and ' + listname[len(listname) -1]
        index = 0  
        new_string = listname[index]  
        while index < len(listname)-1:
            new_string = new_string + listname[index + 1]

            index = index + 1
            if index == len(listname)-1:
                print('\n') 
                print(new_string)

    elif listname[len(listname) - 1] == '7':
        listname[len(listname) - 1] = 'and ' + listname[len(listname) -1]
        index = 0  
        new_string = listname[index]  
        while index < len(listname)-1:
            new_string = new_string + listname[index + 1]

            index = index + 1
            if index == len(listname)-1:
                print('\n') 
                print(new_string)

    elif listname[len(listname) - 1] == '8':
         listname[len(listname) - 1] = 'and ' + listname[len(listname) -1]
         index = 0  
         new_string = listname[index]  
         while index < len(listname)-1:
            new_string = new_string + listname[index + 1]

            index = index + 1
            if index == len(listname)-1:
                print('\n') 
                print(new_string)

    elif listname[len(listname) - 1] == '9':
         listname[len(listname) - 1] = 'and ' + listname[len(listname) -1]
         index = 0  
         new_string = listname[index]  
         while index < len(listname)-1:
            new_string = new_string + listname[index + 1]

            index = index + 1
            if index == len(listname)-1:
                print('\n') 
                print(new_string)

    elif listname[len(listname) - 1] == 'a':
        listname[len(listname) - 1] = 'and ' + listname[len(listname) -1] #This is where I need the help in this elif statement....
        index = 0  
        new_string = listname[index]  
        while index < len(listname)-1:
            new_string = new_string + listname[index + 1]

            index = index + 1
            if index == len(listname)-1:
                print('\n') 
                print(new_string)

    else:
        print('\n') 
        print('Please enter lower case letters')
        exit

commacode(my_input)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why so long?
Here's mine:

```
spam = ['apple', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']

def func(a):
    a[-1] = 'and '+ a[-1]
    print(a)

func(spam)
```

By the way, I am reading this book but I didn't reach the etc stuff yet, did I answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your efforts. It does not quite answer my question. This code from another forum does answer my question though:

```
#Celine Hagbard from reddit.com slightly modified. It works!
s = input('Please enter a list of words and or numbers separated by commas:\n')
print(" and ".join(s.rsplit(",",1)))
```

And yes in much fewer lines than I could manage.

Answer (score 0):

```
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']

# function
def func(list):        
    string = ''        
    for item in list:
        string = string + str(item)

        # adding 'and' as last second item in the string
        if list.index(item) == (len(list)-2):
            string = string + ', and '

        # No comma after last item in the string
        elif list.index(item) == (len(list)-1):
            string = string

        else:
            string = string + ', '

    return string

print(func(spam))
```

## OUTPUT

apples, bananas, tofu, and cats

Answer (score 0):

```
spam = [1, 2, 3, 4, 'jeremy', 'anna']

# Function

def func(list):        
    string = ''        
    for item in list:
        string = string + str(item)

        # adding 'and' as last second item in the string
        if list.index(item) == (len(list)-2):
            string = string + ', and '

        # No comma after last item in the string
        elif list.index(item) == (len(list)-1):
            string = string

        else:
            string = string + ', '

    return string

# function calling

print(func(spam))
```

## OUTPUT

1, 2, 3, 4, jeremy, and anna